# Handling sessions between different ports

Tags: php, ajax, session

Our problem is that we use one server that listens to port 80 and port 8080 where the ports map to the database and website, respectively. The reason for this separation is due to technical issues (it's not an option to merge these). The "database"-server can handle PHP, but not the latter.

We're are trying to implement sessions using PHP-scripts. The database holding the users is an mySQL-database, and the sessions are for login-functionality of users. We use jQuery's Ajax-function to obtain the login-dialog-box which is coded on the database-server.

If we test the login-dialog-box on the database-server, it's all good. We get the same session id each time. However, when we try use it on the website-server (after loading it with an Ajax-call) we receive a new session id for each request (i.e., each time we do something)! So we are unable to use sessions to keep track of things since we are unable to keep the session id linked to the "active session" (that didn't sound as good as I hoped).

We are not certain of what happens here, but suspect that the database-server sees each request as "a new user". Makes sense?

How can we solve this problem?

In advance, thanks! :-)

*Sidenote:*
Not sure it's relevant, but we've seen a lot of topics asking about it: Yes, we have started the session! :-)

Comment: webservers only see only what's sent to them. It's the browser that decides if/when a cookie should be sent back. Somehow it's deciding your webserver environment is two different cookie domains, and isn't sending the session cookie back.

Comment: @MarcB Okay, but is there a way go get around this? Is there something I can send to the database-server with the Ajax call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pecka, if I'm understanding you correctly all authentication is happening at the "database server," correct?  If so, the AJAX call is only returning the database servers' response and not the cookie that it would normally use for helping track your session.

Double check me by looking at the HTTP headers exchanged during the AJAX call, but I think you are only getting the visible content returned by the "Database server."

To check out the headers, you can use something like Firefox with the Live Headers add-on.  https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/live-http-headers/

If I missed my understanding, post back and I'll give it another shot.

---

Pecka, based one what I'm understanding, I can make one suggestion as to how to solve your problem, but I'll preface it by saying I'm not wild about the implications to security and if it were me, I'd work on getting the webserver to use PHP.  That being said...

You can have your database server pass an encrypted token back in it's response, something like this:

```
if( [ENTER CRITERIA FOR CHECKING LOGIN HERE ]) {
    $hashSalt = 'PleasePr0tectM3';
    $token = md5($_POST['username' .date('mdY') .$hashSalt);
    echo $token;
 }
```

It has to be something the webserver can also calculate on it's end based only on input given.  Then the webserver creates the same hash and if they match, you have the webserver issue them session credentials.

It's ugly, but it just might work.

Let me know.  :)

Comment: You seem to be right! :-) When I try to log on (whose code lies on the database-server) I only get a response from the database-server. When I enter the website page which contain code from the website and the login box, I get three responses: 1) the "normal" response from the page, 2) the response from the Ajax-call made to get the login box, and 3) one from jQuery (not relevant, it only gets the library). How can we can around this? EDIT: 1) and 2) got different ID's

Comment: I see that I've might have been unclear about the scenarios. What's correct is that when I enter the site that contains elements from the website (website-server) and the login box (database-server), I get the three responses described above. When I click "login", a request is sent to a PHP-script on the database-server, and I only get one header which is from the database-server.

Comment: After some discussion on the project, we've decided to move our users to the website-server. This didn't seem like a feasible thing to do before, but we've probably found a way now. As you pointed out it might be a security risk using hashing of usernames and so on, so this other approach will help us ensure the security. Thanks for help and insight! :-)

Comment: No problem.  Happy you're able to consolidate.